# connecting two wireless gateways routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

The IP address of the router B970b is 192.168.1.1 and B683 is 192.168.1.2 i think they are in the same network....should i change the ip address of either one of them to 192.168.2.1..?

Basically the thing is i want to have access to internet and printers at the same time,as i have the B970b which has the access to internet and the printers are connected to B683 router through a LAN cable and if i have to give out a print while i am on the surfing internet i have to first migrate to another network and then give out the print which is not productive at all and i cant connect the printers directly to the B970b router as they are separated by a long distance as printers are in one cornor of the room and the B970b router is on the other net.

Hence i thought of bridging two wireless routers wirelessly after research i found that feature isnt compatable with the make and model of routers that i have.Hence i have switch the option of connecting both the routers throught a striaght through cable.

But one question strikes me...lets say i have changed the ip address to 192.168.2.1 of either one of those two routers and have connected them through straight through cable should i have to make the router with internet B970b as access point and the B683 as wirelelss bridge (or) both of them can independently function with their DHCP's still enables and i can still have the access to the printer when i am connected to B970b router....?

Just to let you know the two routers mentioned above i.e., Huawei B970b and huawei B683 are wireless gateways routers and I also do have a Linksys WAG200G ADSL router although its not used anywhere but please do suggest me a way around if it could be utilised can i connect two printers to this ADSL router and connect the huawei B970b 
through this very ADSL router coz the Huawei B683 wireless gateway was also serving the same purpose of providing printer access can it be replaced by the Linksys WAG200G ADSL router that i have..?

[network layout](http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/attachment.php?attachmentid=41482&d=1362394864)

I know its a lot to ask....thank your for your time.

Regards,
Amer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the only way to connect them together is with a cable if they will not be compatible with each other for wireless bridging.

You will need to do the following:

- Turn OFF DHCP Server on the B683, once they are connected together the B970b will do all the DHCP work
- Make sure the IP address for the B683 is in the same range as the network for the B970b and outside the DHCP server scope of the B970b. They seem to already be in the same range e.g. 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2 so you should just need to check that the B970b isn't going to offer 192.168.1.2 as an IP address via DHCP
- Connect a cable between the routers into/from a LAN port on each

Now whenever a client connects to either router, wired or wireless, the IP address will be provided by DHCP from the B970b only, and all the clients connected to either router will be able to talk to each other.

Comment: I come Bearing Good News..

i connected the two routers as i have planned it through a straight-through cable and guess what it worked perfectly fine.....now i have acces to printers and also to the net..



Issue is officially resolved..... Thank you for all your support guys espically all those who had the patience to read my query and took out time to answer it...i really appreciate it...cheers ;)